# Unable to access or use Node's fs module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

When I try use the fs module that node provides I get the error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.u [as env] (/home/julien/code/piarm/src/build/piarm.js:1:708)
    at Object.u.read (/home/julien/code/piarm/src/build/piarm.js:1:1186)
    at Object../tests/GPIO (/home/julien/code/piarm/src/build/piarm.js:1:980)
    at u (/home/julien/code/piarm/src/build/piarm.js:1:316)
    at e (/home/julien/code/piarm/src/build/piarm.js:1:483)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/julien/code/piarm/src/build/piarm.js:1:500)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

I tried to reinstall node and on my second try the error changed to this:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'exists'
    at Object.u [as env] (/data/piarm.js:1:708)
    at Object.u.read (/data/piarm.js:1:1190)
    at Object../tests/GPIO (/data/piarm.js:1:984)
    at u (/data/piarm.js:1:316)
    at e (/data/piarm.js:1:483)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/data/piarm.js:1:500)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';

function env() {

    fs.exists('.env', function(exists) {
        if (exists) {

            console.log('true')
        } else {
            console.log('false')
        }
    });
}
export { env };
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit** I am Using a transpiler, therefore my `import` is syntactically the same as a `require();`

**Edit** My gulp file

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var babelify = require('babelify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var stream = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');

var paths = {
    js: './src/piarm/**/*.js'
};

gulp.task('build', function () {
    browserify({
        entries: './src/piarm/piarm.js',
        debug: true
    })
        .transform(babelify)
        .bundle()
        .pipe(stream('piarm.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/build'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['build']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

Update I can confirm that the error is in my transpiler. I wrote the same code in es5 and ran it with my node. Is there any bad compatibility with the transpilers I am using in my gulp file?

Comment: node doesn't support `import` keyword yet, I guess

Comment: If that was so then fs would be undefined as in my first error, but after a reinstall is says that the imported object does not contain the specified methods. If I understand it correctly - then it is importing it. Also I am using a transpiler from es6 - es5

Comment: To add to that, I just tried `var fs = require('fs');` with the same result

Comment: Which transpiler? How do you call it? Which Node version are you using?

Comment: I am using babel. I will include my gulp file. Node version `v0.12.4`.

Comment: **Update** I can confirm that the error is in my transpiler. I wrote the same code in es5 and ran it with my node. Is there any bad compatibility with the transpilers I am using in my gulp file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the babel transpiler. babelify does not support node imports

Answer (score 0):

In node, you don't import, you require :)

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: The OP already explained that he's using a transpiler, and also that a plain `require()` didn't work either.

Comment: @robertklep, his question was edited AFTER I answered.

Comment: @idoberko2 I spoke about it in the comments. But it is not important - I am looking for a solution here

Comment: @idoberko2 fair enough, although I inferred from the syntax and the `ecmascript-6` tag that he was at least using a transpiler of some sorts.